# Trying to use fullpage.js with barba.js

Tags: javascript

I making a site that have a 6 section in the homepage with links to some work. I trying to use barba view like this but doesn't work. Also I'm a little new with this

```
var Homepage = Barba.BaseView.extend({
    namespace: 'project',
    onEnter: function() {                         
        // The new Container is ready and attached to the DOM.
    },
    onEnterCompleted: function() {                            
        $.fn.fullpage.destroy();                      
        // The Transition has just finished.
    },
    onLeave: function() {                         
        // A new Transition toward a new page has just started.
    },
    onLeaveCompleted: function() { 
        $.fp.fullpage.reBuild();
        // The Container has just been removed from the DOM.
    }
});

// Don't forget to init the view!
Homepage.init();
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: The hopage have a fullpage.js and the project in each section are meant to normal scroll. When i go to the project i call the fullpage destroy to make it scrollable, but i go back to the home page the fullpage.js doesn't respond, or reinizied.